# move neo4j database from one server to another

Tags: database, neo4j, database-migration, graph-databases

I have a server that uses neo4j 3.5.x with docker. Now I want to move that database to another server.

This time I see that neo4j released 4.0. I just copied `data` folder which contains only `graph.db`

I run the script I used last time

`sudo docker run --name vis --restart unless-stopped --log-opt max-size=50m --log-opt max-file=10 -p3001:7474 -p3002:7473 -p3003:3003 -d -v /data:/data -v /conf:/conf -v /logs:/logs --env NEO4J_AUTH=none neo4j`

When I run this I see that I can reach it from 7474 which is fine. BUT it asks password to see the data. Though I didn't set a password WHY IT ASKS?

I tried everything possible like **neo4j**, **123**, **1234**, **test** or live it empty. none worked.

it gives error

> neo4j-driver.chunkhash.bundle.js:1 WebSocket connection to 'ws://0.0.0.0:7687/' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_ADDRESS_INVALID

Is there a proper/robust way to import data between neo4j database servers? Can I use this https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/export-sub-graph-to-cypher-and-import/

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but I just upgraded my server from 3.5 to 4.0. The data storage format seems to have changed, and the logs told me to add `dbms.allow_upgrade=true` in my `neo4j.conf` file. Then the server started fine.

Comment: Why neo4j community edition does not provide a backup method? A migration method? This must be one of the first things a database software have to do properly and easily.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to the Neo4j desktop, and then select the graph. Open up Manage options. Then choose Open Terminal.

Once there you can use the database backup command. (Here is an example)
`bin\neo4j-admin backup --backup-dir=c:/backup --name=graph.db-20200107`

This will backup the database to the specified backup directory.

Then you can zip that backup directory, and then unzip the backup directory, and restore it on the new server.
(Here is an example)

```
bin\neo4j-admin restore --from=c:/backup/graph.db-20200107 --database=graph.db --force=true
```

Note: The 'graph.db-20200107' is an example of the name that you give the database backup. You can name it whatever you want.

-yyyguy

Comment: I was using docker but I switched to Neo4j desktop. Neo4j should provide better methods to move database or take a backup. Copy-pasting graph.db folder cannot be an acceptable method